# Error trying to compile Linux Source Code

Tags: linux

I'm not very good into coding/programming but I'm trying to compile Linux Source.

Following errormessage shows up:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  char *ptr = strchr( in, ch );
```

While "googling" around I could't find a helpfull answer.
I guess this is the part where it fails:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Parses an IP address string
///
/// @param[out] out array containing the IP address in raw 4-byte format
/// @param in string containing an IP address in 'nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn'
///     notation
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int parseIP( uint8_t *out, const char *in )
{
        in_addr addr, haddr;
        int c = 0;
        int ch = '.';
        char *ptr = strchr( in, ch );

        while( ptr ) {
                ++c;
                ptr = strchr( ptr + 1, ch );
        }

        if( c != 3 )
                return -EINVAL;

        if( inet_aton( in, &addr ) == 0 )
                return -EINVAL;

        haddr.s_addr = ntohl( addr.s_addr );

        for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
                out[ i ] = ((uint8_t *)&haddr.s_addr)[ 3 - i ];

        return 0;
}
```

Hopefully anyone can help.

Regards,
Mark

Hi David,

I've found the part were it's been called and tried to change it, but still same errormessage while using th 'make' command.

```
 case 'i':
                        if( getuid() != 0 ) {
                                std::cerr << "Error: you need to have "
                                                "root privileges in "
                                                "order to use the "
                                                "-i/--ipaddr option"
                                                << std::endl;
                                exit( 1 );
                        }

                        if( strncmp( optarg, "dhcp", 4 ) == 0 &&
                                        strlen( optarg ) == 4 )
                                opt_devip_dhcp = 1;
                        else if( parseIP( opt_devip, (char *)optarg ) ) {
                                std::cerr << "Error: bad IP address" <<
                                                std::endl;
                                exit( 3 );
                        }

                        opt_devip_set = 1;
                        break;
                case 'm':
                        if( parseIP( opt_devmask, (char *)optarg ) ) {
                                std::cerr << "Error: bad network mask" <<
                                                std::endl;
                                exit( 7 );
                        }

                        opt_devmask_set = 1;
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int parseIP( uint8_t *out, const char *in )
```

You need to find where `parseIP` is called in your main program. See above how the second argument is `const char *in`. You summize correctly that is probably where the error is generated. If you check in your main program where `parseIP` is called, you will probably find your program passing it a `char *` argument instead of `const char *`. You can correct this in the code by casting the value passed to `parseIP` to (char *) Example: if you find this:

```
somevar = parseIP( outvar, stringin )
```

Cast the second argument to `(char *)`:

```
somevar = parseIP( outvar, (char *)stringin )
```

Or you can probably just `cheat` with the compiler. It is giving you a hint on how to do it. Notice the `[-fpermissive]` as part of the warning. You can more than likely just pass the `-fpermissive` flag to the compiler and have it work. If you were compiling with:

```
gcc -Wall -o outfile yourfile.cpp
```

Try it with:

```
gcc -Wall -o outfile yourfile.cpp -fpermissive
```

Now, all the legal qualifications and disclaimers apply, you are better fixing the reason you are getting that warning/error as set forth above, but you can also just pass `-fpermissive` as a temporary workaround most of the time.